# External Hard Drive Issue on mac

Tags: permissions, osx, ls, hard-disk, mkdir

After the `cd /Volumes` command when I type `ls` it shows me my hard drive name twice, with different permissions. After that when I try to use `mkdir` to create a directory in the external hard drive I'm unable to do so and it shows permission denied.

The name of my hard drive is Harshvardhan.

Here is the symptom:

```
Harshvardhans-MacBook-Pro:/ Sherlock$ ls
Applications            Users             etc                 sbin
Library                 Volumes           home                tmp
Network                 bin               mach_kernel         usr
System                  cores             net                 var
User Information        dev               private
Harshvardhans-MacBook-Pro:/ Sherlock$ cd /Volumes
Harshvardhans MacBook Pro:Volumes Sherlock$ ls -l
total 8
drwx------+  2 Sherlock  admin    68 Sep 23 22:00 Harshvardhan
drwxrwxr-x  31 Sherlock  staff  1122 Sep 23 21:56 Harshvardhan
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root      admin     1 Sep 12 21:29 Macintosh HD -> /
Harshvardhans-MacBook Pro:Volumes Sherlock$ mkdir Harshvardhan/ECEC
mkdir: Harshvardhan/ECEC: Permission denied
Harshvardhans-MacBook-Pro:Volumes Sherlock$ cd Harshvardhan
Harshvardhans-MacBook-Pro:Harshvardhan Sherlock$ mkdir ECEC
mkdir: ECEC: Permission denied
Harshvardhans-MacBook-Pro:Harshvardhan Sherlock$
```

Here is the output of `mount`:

```
/dev/disk0s2 on / (hfs, local, journaled)
devfs on /dev (devfs, local, nobrowse)
map -hosts on /net (autofs, nosuid, automounted, nobrowse)
map auto_home on /home (autofs, automounted, nobrowse)
/dev/disk1s2 on /Volumes/Harshvardhan  (hfs, local, nodev, nosuid, journaled, noowners)
```

And here is the output of `df -h`:

```
Filesystem      Size   Used  Avail Capacity iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk0s2   112Gi   29Gi   83Gi    26% 7591932  21820436   26%   /
devfs          185Ki  185Ki    0Bi   100%     640         0  100%   /dev
map -hosts       0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0         0  100%   /net
map auto_home    0Bi    0Bi    0Bi   100%       0         0  100%   /home
/dev/disk1s2   931Gi   22Gi  909Gi     3% 5887882 238218784    2%   /Volumes/Harshvardhan
```

Comment: i am sorry, can you help me out with this problem?

Comment: This is not the answer, just thinking out loud: `df -h` should list mount point information. Maybe there is a way to unmount the 'wrong' drive? Since share the same name might have to look at inode level. Definitely worth a man unmount to see. I hope it gets you on your way.

Comment: I have added the output of the mount and df -h commands

Answer (score 0):

You appear to have a broken Fusion drive. You can see this in the `df -h` results: you have one ~128 GB disk (`/dev/disk0`) and one 1 TB disk (`/dev/disk1`), both mounted at the root. The Fusion technology is supposed to bond these two together seamlessly, shuffling files back and forth between the volumes so they appear to be one, but they are really two separate volumes. This pair bond appears to have broken.

[According to Apple](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5446?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US), Disk Utility may or may not be able to repair this. Restoring the pair bond might require erasing the disks. Make a backup before you proceed!

No, scratch that: Make two.

Comment: how do I solve this problem? Do i need to speak to apple?

Comment: @HarshvardhanAgrawal: I thought my answer and the Apple support article I linked to made that clear: 1. Make one or two backups while you still have the disks in a readable condition. 2. See if Disk Utility will repair  the disk. It may be able to do it online, it may have to reboot, and it may have to reformat and reinstall the OS.

Comment: @HarshvardhanAgrawal: By the way, if this really is the problem, your question is mistitled: it is the *internal* disks with the problem, not an external disk.